# Preserve gatsby-images between builds on Netlify

Tags: gatsby, netlify

I have a pretty large Gatsby site (8000+ pages) running on Netlify and using Gatsby-image for image optimization. The images pretty much never change but each time I deploy the processing of them takes 30+ minutes with the exact same output every time. The image processing also makes the build process take more than the 15 minutes allowed by Netlify meaning I can't use their git workflow for deployments. If I could just somehow preserve the images between builds I could drastically reduce the build time and move back to git-based deployments.

Did anyone run into this problem and/or have any suggestions for possible workarounds?

Comment: How are you building and pushing to Netlify now given the 30 minute build time?

Comment: I'm building locally and deploying through the CLI.. That in turn frequently times out during the upload process.

Comment: At what step in the build process does Gatsby time out and what step does the Netlify CLI time out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [gatsby-plugin-netlify-cache](https://github.com/axe312ger/gatsby-plugin-netlify-cache). I believe it is exactly what you need. I was able to get a build from 15 minutes down to about 2 just by dropping it in!

Comment: Use caution with that plugin. [Issue #15](https://github.com/axe312ger/gatsby-plugin-netlify-cache/issues/15) could be a show stopper.

Comment: Problem is I cannot get the build up in the first place so there's nothing for it to cache. I tried adding pages incrementally but it starts timing out to early for it to be a practical solution.

Comment: @talves Interesting, thanks for the heads up about that plugin. Hopefully there's a solution soon.